# When brewing water Kefir my wire bail stopper blew off

Tags: fermentation, bottling

I am trying to salvage my one fermenting bottle and wondered if anyone knows how to get the dern top/bail stopper back on the bottle. 
When I went to open my water kefir it shot liquid everywhere and the top blew completely off. the whole mechanism. I've tried to get it back on but no luck.
is it totalled?

Comment: [Is this a swing-top bottle](http://www.ebottles.com/bottlefamilyimages/thumb/SWING_TOP_ROUND_WIRE_BAIL_GLASS_BOTTLES.jpg)?

Comment: Without a picture its hard to tell.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Kefir.  Which is a fermented milk product.  Not beer or wine.

Comment: It is water kefir, different from milk kefir. I asked at this site because y'all talk about fermenting. I figured SOMEONE over there has dealt with this kind of bottle, no matter what I'm brewing. Not sure why kefir isn't allowed on this site. Yes, it is a swing top bottle.

Comment: The contents of what you are brewing are less significant when compared to the actual issue at hand, which is your bottle.  As stated earlier, if you can post a couple of pictures of the bottle, we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Kefir is both fermented (like beer) and cultured with bacteria (like yogurt).

Answer (score 1):

You can buy replacement closures online or at brewstores (http://store.defalcowines.com/catalog/product_20216_Swingtop_Replacement_Tops_each_cat_289.html).

Given this, you can probably get the wire back in. If you don't want to buy a new one, you may have to bend the old one with pliers to be able to fit (assuming the force of the closure coming off bent the wire).